# Create a custum Sharepoint list and add items problems

Tags: visual-studio, list, object, sharepoint

Im new to SharePoint programming, or programming at all for that case. My problem is that I get a error-message when I try to go to my sharepoint site after I debugged this oode (it worked fine in visual studio). I don't know whats wrong? The error message i get is:
"Server Error in '/' Application.
0x80004005Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests.  To allow updates on a GET, set the 'AllowUnsafeUpdates' property on SPWeb."
I've read that you got to allow safe updates? but is that the case? I think maybe it is my code that is not right... Please help :)

```
// choose your site
            SPSite site = new SPSite("http://....");
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            //Add a list to the choosen site
            SPListCollection lists = web.Lists;

            // create new Generic list called "OrdersList"
            lists.Add("OrdersTest", "All of my testorders will be here", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
            //Add the new list to the website
            SPList newList = web.Lists["OrdersTest"];
            // create Number type new column called "OrderID"
            newList.Fields.Add("OrderID", SPFieldType.Number, true);
            // create Number type new column called "OrderNumber"
            newList.Fields.Add("OrderNumber", SPFieldType.Number, true);
            // create Text type new column called "OrderProducts"
            newList.Fields.Add("OrderProducts", SPFieldType.Text, true);
            newList.Update();

            //Create a object to that list
            SPListItem newOrder = newList.AddItem();
            //Add a new item
            newOrder["OrderID"] = 1;
            newOrder["OrderNumber"] = 1;
            newOrder["OrderProducts"] = "Icecream";
            newOrder.Update();


            // create new Generic list called "ProductTest"
            lists.Add("ProductTest", "All of my testproducts will be here", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
            //Add the new list to the website
            SPList newList2 = web.Lists["ProductTest"];
            // create Number type new column called "ProductID"
            newList2.Fields.Add("ProductID", SPFieldType.Number, true);
            // create Text type new column called "ProductName"
            newList2.Fields.Add("ProductName", SPFieldType.Text, true);
            // create Number type new column called "OrderID"
            newList2.Fields.Add("ProductPrice", SPFieldType.Number, true);

            //Create a object to that list
            SPListItem nyProduct = newList2.AddItem();
            //Add a new item
            nyProduct["ProductID"] = 1;
            nyProduct["ProductName"] = "Icecream";
            nyProduct["ProductPrice"] = 13;
            nyProduct.Update();
```

Comment: Why you get SPWeb object using SPContext.Current and SPSite object using constructor? Also i do not see that your code uses "site" variable anywhere so you probably can remove it.

Comment: Regarding the error - if you get "Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests" error generally the cause is not in the code itself but in location where you call. Is this code from some web part or custom page?

Comment: The code is in page load from a Web Part. Ok so if I use it like this: // choose your site
            SPSite site = new SPSite("http://server1/sites/SPU13/");
            SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

Comment: this looks correct but it won't fix your problem. Why do you need to create lists on page load? It sounds odd.

Comment: Yeah maybe, I just have an assignment to create two list, one orders and one products and then connect them. I thought that the easiest way to create lists is when the webpart is activated on the site so i don't have to push extra buttuns and stuff.. Should I put it in another method?

Comment: It sounds really messy to me to use web part to do one time job )). Have you tried creating console application and putting you code there? Or powershell script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set AllowUnsafeUpdates to true for updating data in get requests.

```
 using(SPSite site = new SPSite("http://...."))
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            bool b = web.AllowUnsafeUpdates;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            try
            {
                //your code
                //create and update list
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //handles errors
            }
            finally
            {
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = b;
            }
        }
```